# Where is _g_config.h in MinGW?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mingw

I'm trying to compile a C++ project with Visual Studio 2008.
The project uses 
    *G_config.h*. 
Therefore, I installed **MinGW 4.6.2**
However, I cannot find G_config.h in MinGW.

How can I get G_config from MinGW?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The header `G_config.h` is not part of *MinGW* (and therefore not required?). The file comes from *cygwin*. Possible you can use the one from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Other/Unsupported/MSYS/msysDVLPR/).

Is your project for linux / cygwin or mingw?

Comment: The project was built on Linux. Now, I am trying to compile it with Visual Studio.

Comment: I also installed cygwin. But _g_config.h is also not in cygwin.

Comment: Can you compile it with mingw (or cygwin) if you remove that file from source? g_config.h is a *"customized"* iostream header. You can also test the g_config i've linked above. There's also one here: http://www.physto.se/~amanda/local/recoos/HTML/usr/include/_G_config.h.html

Comment: though it's possible you need libc?

Comment: after i added _g_config.h, it raised a lot of errors: 2>C:\cygwin\usr\include\sys/_types.h(36) : error C2144: syntax error : '__int64' should be preceded by ';'
2>C:\cygwin\usr\include\sys/_types.h(36) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2>C:\cygwin\usr\include\sys/_types.h(83) : error C4980: '__value' : use of this keyword requires /clr:oldSyntax command line option
2>C:\cygwin\usr\include\sys/_types.h(83) : error C2059: syntax error : '__value'
2>C:\cygwin\usr\include\sys/reent.h(185) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_read'

Comment: What happens if you remove the file (or the `#include`)?